# Posting and retrieving latest json object with React component

Tags: reactjs, json-server

I have built a React component where I retrieve object from json file, save it in state and display it on my page. All working but now I want to take it to the next step and not sure how to go about.

My plan is once a user submits the form then the input is added to json file (json-server), not sure how I am going to do this but see there is some documentation how to do it with fetch. But then the tricky part, how can I display the last entry from the json file using fetch? I know I can access the last element by using -1 but not sure how to go about in my current code.

Here is snippet from the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Result extends Component {

    state = {
        loading: true,
        consumer: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const url = "http://localhost:3004/results";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ consumer: data.consumer[0], loading: false });
        console.log(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="result">
                {this.state.loading || !this.state.consumer ? (
                    <div>retrieving coupon...</div>
                ) : (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="result-left">
                                <p>Gift card</p>
                                <p>
                                    <span id="coupon-displayNumber">
                                        {this.state.consumer.giftcardnumber}
                                    </span>
                                    <span id="coupon-displayCode">
                                        <span> {this.state.consumer.code}</span>
                                    </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="result-right">
                                <p>-${this.state.consumer.price}</p>
                            </div>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Result;
```

Comment: Where is the form you are talking about?

Comment: From what I understood, you can check for the success of the submitted form and use the entered values in the form to render your element. If you want some extra info you may want to rend that in the response of your POST.

Comment: @k3lly.dev the form is in another component. My question is how am I going to display the data and not relevant to the form, do you want to see the form as well?

Comment: @ShobhitChittora I was thinking about this approach as well, saving in state and displaying it like I did above but my objective is to add this input to json file.

Comment: `Result` component should not call api for get. The component hosting form can take care of post and get call. Initially you could fetch all data and pass to `Result` component. Add data using form(post call) to json-server. Post call returns added data and that data could be passed to `Result` component. If you want data other than newly added data you could filter from whole data and send to 'Result' component.

Comment: What i suggested is the approach called optimistic updates. You update the ui being optimistic about your file writes. And when the server responds with the correct status or post response, you either rollback or keep the optimistic update as is. Also I assume that this json file is on a server and you interact with it using a rest api of some sorts.

Comment: Ok so I thought about it in a more React way and what I am trying to do is display data from json file which works but the way I wanted to approach it is a little bit far fetched. I went back to drawing board and changed it a bit. I am not pulling data from the api server anymore but passing the state and using as props to display on the component. For the data added to api I am just using post method.